# The IN function in xslt test boolean expression

Tags: xml, xslt

can't find the answer anywhere whether you can do `test="$var in ('Val1','Val2','Val3')"` in XSLT instead of doing `test="$var='Val1' or $var='Val2' or $var='Val3'"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In XSLT 1.0, you can use the [`contains()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-contains) function:**

```
test(contains('Val1,Val2,Val3',$var))`
```

It returns a boolean result, testing whether the first string contains the second string.

A common way to help reduce false-positive results for partial string matches is to use a delimiter and pad the values with that delimiter:

```
test="contains(' Val1 Val2 Val3 ', concat(' ',$var,' '))
```

That way, if the value of `$var` was "`Val`", it would only return true if "`Val`" were added to the list of values being tested.

**In XSLT 2.0, you could use:**

```
test="$var = ('Val1','Val2','Val3')"
```

It will return true if `$var` is equal to any of the items in the sequence (which is what you define when you have a comma separated list of values inside of parenthesis).

**Another XSLT 2.0 solution:**

```
test="some $value in ('Val1','Val2','Val3') satisfies $var=$value"
```

Answer (score 1):

**I. XPath 1.0 / XSLT 1.0**

**Use**:

```
contains(concat($Sep, 'Val1', $Sep, 'Val2', $Sep, 'Val3', $Sep),
         concat($Sep, $var, $Sep)
        )
```

where `$Sep` is a string that is guaranteed not to appear in any of the values.

The concatenation is nesessary to exclude false positives when one or more of the values start-with or end-with the value of `$var`.

**The comparison is even easier if `'Val1'`, `'Val2'` and `'Val3'` are text nodes (say of `/a/b`)**:

```
$var = /a/b
```

**II. XPath 2.0 (XSLT 2.0)**

```
$var = ('Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3')
```

Answer (score 0):

XSLT/XPath doesn't have support for IN expressions.

But you can to store those values into an XML fragment and search inside it.